# Perl Spreadsheet::ParseXLSX err, format error: can't find EOCD signature help!

Tags: perl

I have a Perl program using Spreadsheet::ParseExcel. However, there are two difficulties that have arisen that I have been unable to figure out how to solve. perl error is follow:

```
format error: can't find EOCD signature
 at /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.12.0/Archive/Zip/Archive.pm line 719
        Archive::Zip::Archive::_findEndOfCentralDirectory('Archive::Zip::Archive=HASH(0x9103b38)', 'IO::File=GLOB(0x91476d8)') called at /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.12.0/Archive/Zip/Archive.pm line 597
        Archive::Zip::Archive::readFromFileHandle('Archive::Zip::Archive=HASH(0x9103b38)', 'IO::File=GLOB(0x91476d8)', '151008171923.xls') called at /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.12.0/Archive/Zip/Archive.pm line 565
        Archive::Zip::Archive::read('Archive::Zip::Archive=HASH(0x9103b38)', '151008171923.xls') called at /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.12.0/Spreadsheet/ParseXLSX.pm line 35
```

Help.

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ。ここはStackOverflowの日本版サイトです。質問は日本語に翻訳してください。そうすれば回答が得られますよ。

Comment: What's the code you're trying to run?

Comment: Thanks Sobrique.

But Self-solve

Code is this

    use strict;
    use warnings;
    use Excel::Reader::XLSX;
    
    my $reader   = Excel::Reader::XLSX->new();
    my $workbook = $reader->read_file( 'Book1.xlsx' ); <- Error is this
    
    exit(0);

but 'Book1.xlsx' has excel2007 workbook encrypt protection.
So Archive.pm seems to have not read.

best regards.